# JavaScript function call desugar

Tags: javascript, call, syntactic-sugar

I've found [this](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) article that says that JavaScript function calls are really just a syntactic sugar for `func.call(...)`.

I would like to ask if that's really true, because I've not found anything like that in the spec (haven't really examined it thoroughly, just brief glance and search for the word `call()`).

It would be really nice if someone could enlighten me, cause if this article is true, my admiration of the EcmaScript language may reduced.

Comment: to anyone who wants to mark this question with -1, I`m open for discussion and will be really glad to know, why is it so important to downvote the question

Comment: I'm writing an answer now. I think it's a perfectly appropriate question.

Comment: "*In the ES5 spec, the call method is described in terms of another, more low level primitive, but it's a very thin wrapper on top of that primitive, so I'm simplifying a bit here.*" - so yes, by that simplification, it would be true. Hint: the primitive that the author is talking about is `[[Call]]`

Comment: but it is not equal to the Function.prototype.call as far as my understanding of the language is considered. Even more, I tested Typescript compiler and made it generate ES3 compatible result (the lowest it can make) and ther was no such thing as the desugaring mentioned by the author of the article.

Comment: Indeed. It isn't really desugar/transpiling/etc. to that. It's just a function of `obj.func()` results in `obj` being the context of `func`. So from a practical sense, you can say that it's the same as `obj.func.call(obj)`, but it's not going to actual desugar/transpile the code itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see why the article would say it, and it kind of is to an extent.

The reason they probably claim that is because functions when used directly are unbound, meaning if I create an object:

```js
const a = { say: function() { console.log(this.message) } };
a.message = 'hello';
a.say();
```

When I run the function `a.say()`, the `this` context inside of `say()` is `a`. That is equivalent to `a.say.call(a)`.

Since I haven't bound that function explicitly, if I pass it somewhere else can call it, it won't necessarily have the context of `a` anymore:

```js
const a = { say: function() { console.log(this.message) } };
const b = {};
a.message = 'hello';
b.message = 'goodbye';
b.say = a.say;
b.say();
```

Notice that even though I copied `a`'s `say()`, when called with `b`, it ended up being called with `b` as it's context (`this`). Thus, it's essentially equivalent to `a.say.call(b)`.

If you explicitly bind the function, then it will always use a fixed context:

```js
const a = { say: function() { console.log(this.message); } };
const b = {};
a.message = 'hello';
b.message = 'goodbye';
b.say = a.say.bind(a);
b.say();
```

With it bound, it'll now always use the context of `a`, even though I may pass the function to other places.

Now, that said, I'm not sure why your admiration would be crippled. I actually find this an awesome feature of the language and makes it very powerful and flexible. It is what allows you to do things like this:

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'))
  .forEach(el => console.log(el.innerHTML));
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

In that example, `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList`, which  doesn't normally have `forEach()`. However, since it is compatible enough, I can use `call()` to pass it to `Array.prototype.slice` to transform it into an `Array` with those elements. (You can also just give it to `forEach()` directly, but I prefer to transform it with `slice()` then do further things.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There seems to be a little misunderstanding. I completely agree with you because the whole "dynamic this" mechanism is brilliant design solution. My question is whether javascript runtimes consume foo(111) "as it is", or do they have to do excessive work and change this call to foo.call(global, 111) in every place of the code

Comment: It kind of does, but it's not a lot of work. It's just determining the context at run-time, which is a really easy thing. Just like everything else at the `global/window` level, `global` is implied on a call like that, so the context is global, but it's not really any work to determine that. It's not changing, its just a determination at execution time of the function.

Comment: is there any chance tha it imacts program execution performance (i assume just-in-time compilation and immediate execution afterwards)?

Comment: No. It's a fundamental thing of JS, so it's going to be lighting fast. Everything  you run always has a context, and that context is always known. In that article, when he talks about desugaring, he's really only saying that for illustrative purposes. It's not even a JIT compiliation. It's just a lookup. It's just how functions work. It's not really any different then how an OO language would determine context for a class method.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Accepted your answer, and also if you don\`t mind. Right now I`m on the edge of exploring really deep parts of the language and sadly not every my question gets such complete answer. I wonder if you can recommend something worth looking into, because MDN is not enough right now and reading spec still hurts. Thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure of any middle ground between those two unfortunately. I usually use MDN, and then when I need to dive deeper, looking at the spec is about the only other reliable place to go. Good luck. =)

Answer (score 0):

> #### The [[Call]] internal method of every function is activated when we call a function (via the call expression, e.g. foo() or with using call and apply methods).

~ Dmitry Soshnikov, [article](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/notes/note-1-ecmascript-bound-functions/#implementation-features) about `.bind`

---

> #### Internal Properties Only Defined for Some Objects
>
> *Internal Property* - `[[Call]]`
>
> *Description* - Executes code associated with the object. Invoked via a function call expression. The arguments are a `this` object and a list containing the `arguments` passed to the function call expression. Objects that implement this internal method are callable.

~ see Table 9 [here](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2) at **Annotated ECMAScript 5.1**
Also see [13.2 Creating Function Objects](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2), `13.2.1 [[Call]]`,
Binding [15.3.4.5](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5), `15.3.4.5.1,5 [[Call]]`

All the steps defined there are of course internal only, so no actual "desugaring" transformation happens, but those internal steps really *DO* resemble it.

---

## tl;dr

I guess that in short you can think of what he says in the article as

> How to mimick what's going on under the roof to better understand the concept.